# Div 100% Height is not working

Tags: css

I am trying to position a content div inside the page but I do not know why the height 100% is not fitting the content div inside the body?
here is my code sample:

```
*{ margin:0;padding: 0;}
html{height:100%; width:100%;}
body{height:100%; width:100%;}
#content{ position:relative; height:100%; width:65%; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#345C54;}
```

and HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/yLmnx/) is the sample link on jsFiddle . As you can see the content div's height  is not fitting on body 100% can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: You mean why the scroll bars appear? It's because of the padding. The element's total height is 100% + 50px padding.

Comment: Hi Juhana , thanks for comment but even without having that this is happening. I removed the padding property but nothing changed!

Comment: Not fitting as in its overflowing or not fitting as in its not taking up the expected size?

Comment: It's kinda hard to say anything since it seems to be working for everyone else except you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed padding to 0px (on jsfiidle link) and it seems right (vertical scrollbar dissapeared)...

```
 #page{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:65%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#345C54;
    padding-top: 0px;
    }
```

Is that what you wanted?

EDIT: 
`padding: 0px;` // instead of padding-top

Comment: But it not working for me! there is still space at the bottom!

Comment: Please see my edit, if no help can you specify what browser do you use?